# Is there a way to define functions in lisp-interactive-mode

Tags: emacs

I often use `lisp-interactive-mode` in emacs a scratch pad calculator, eg. I'll have something like this

```
(* 100 (/ 60 5) 459) ;; Expected QPS for front end
```

where this corresponds to some calculation I'm making (in this case QPS)

I would like to bind the result of this calculation to a function or variable, so that I can use it in other calculations. Is this possible?

Comment: How about?:  `(setq sam-lee (* 100 (/ 60 5) 459))`  Then test it out by typing:  `M-x describe-variable RET sam-lee RET`  That example does not require any major-mode to work.

Comment: Yes, you can evaluate *any* elisp form in `lisp-interactive-mode`, so you can define functions or set variables exactly as you would in any other elisp code. This mode is really just a convenience mode for arbitrary evaluations.